# Calling array object in src does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, svelte, sveltekit

I have an array :

```
let x = '';
let elements = [
            { icon:"Home",name:'Home',page:'Page1' },
            { icon:'Cube',name:'New',page:'Page2' }];
```

I am looping in it:

```
{#each elements as { icon, name, page }, i}
                        
                        <Icon src={icon} size="24" />
```

This here does not work: src={icon}

Correct way should be like this:

```
<Icon src="{Filter}" solid />
```

If I replace the {icon} with string it works! Can someone tell me why?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because `<Icon src="xxx" />` does not expect a *string* but an *object*.  If you import the icons from the library and log them you will see they follow the format:

```
{
  "default": {
    "a": {
      "fill": "none",
      "viewBox": "0 0 24 24",
      "stroke": "currentColor",
      "aria-hidden": "true"
    },
    "path": [
      {
        "stroke-linecap": "round",
        "stroke-linejoin": "round",
        "stroke-width": "2",
        "d": "M5 10l7-7m0 0l7 7m-7-7v18"
      }
    ]
  },
  "solid": {
    "a": {
      "viewBox": "0 0 20 20",
      "fill": "currentColor",
      "aria-hidden": "true"
    },
    "path": [
      {
        "fill-rule": "evenodd",
        "d": "M3.293 9.707a1 1 0 010-1.414l6-6a1 1 0 011.414 0l6 6a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L11 5.414V17a1 1 0 11-2 0V5.414L4.707 9.707a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z",
        "clip-rule": "evenodd"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So what you need to do is either import the icons and use those in your element array as another answer already mentions.  Or alternatively, import **all** icons in your application and do something like

```html
<Icon src={allIcons[name]} />
```

but then you lose tree shaking and make your bundle a lot bigger.

Comment: you are correct but even doing it like this it gives me an error: Home is not defined.Even if I import Home at the top with allIcons still cant make it work.The correct way for this to work is <Icon src="{Filter}" solid /> ,even if in my array I make the icon:  "{Home}",still the problem persists.let me know your thoughts

Comment: if you do `import { Home } from '...';` you can show it with `src={icon}` provided you did `{ src: Home }`

Comment: sorry but I just did both of the above also icon: `src: "{  Home }"` and it still doesnt work, I moved on to another library but dont know why it doest work

Comment: it probably doesn't work because you are mixing strings and objects

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the icon names and use in `elements` array without quotes.

```
    <script>
    import { Icon, Home, Cube } from "svelte-hero-icons";
    let elements = [
       { icon: Home, name: "Home", page: "Page1" },
       { icon: Cube, name: "New", page: "Page2" }];
    </script>
```

```
    <div>
    {#each elements as { icon, name, page }, i}
        <Icon src={icon} size="32" />
    {/each}
    </div>
```

Comment: seriously?...do us both a favor and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

i have used p tag instead of icon but you can use or generated icon with
[image: screenshot]

Comment: click on the above text.

Comment: I know this but when I loop inside somehow its not recognized ,even if I make the array like this: icon:` '"{Home}"'` it still does not work...do not know why,you can try it yourself I use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-hero-icons

Comment: provide detailed solution instead of direct posting a link.

Comment: Please do not screenshot code, it is inaccessible; insert it as text instead.